# beamer overlay: carry text over from previous slide

Tags: beamer, overlays

This code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1>
    Text on slide 1 and 2
    \onslide<2>
    Text on slide 1 and 2\\
    Text on slide 2
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

creates the output

[image]

As the phrase

> Text on slide 1 and 2

is used both on slides 1 and 2 I have to repeat it 1 time. Wouldn't it be so much better if I could carry it over from the previous slide and then just append

> Text on slide 2

to it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, that's what `\pause` does. `Text on slide 1 and 2
    \pause
    Text on slide 1 and 2\\
    Text on slide 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that's what the `\pause` command does.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    Text on slide 1 and 2\\
    \pause
    Text on slide 2
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for converting your comment into an answer - even on such a busy day for you!

Comment: @samcarter Casting a shadow is actually not so time consuming, especially with Ti*k*Z ;-)